# Pact: Write different interactions with same endpoint

Tags: javascript, integration-testing, pact

I have a situation where I wrote 2 interactions with same endpoint.
Even though I am passing different query in with_request option, i am getting below error -

```
Error: Multiple interaction found for GET /a1/configurations?includeDeleted=true&
```

**First interaction:**

```
withRequest: {
          method: "GET",
          path: `/a1/configurations`,
          query: {
            includeDeleted: "false",
          }
}
```

**Second interaction:**

```
withRequest: {
          method: "GET",
          path: `/a1/configurations`,
          query: {
            includeDeleted: "true",
          }
}
```

Can anyone help me in getting a way to fulfil this requirement ?

Thanking you !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that both of your requests have the same name, set by `uponReceiving`.

The error message suggests that your code is something like:

```
uponReceiving: 'GET /a1/configurations?includeDeleted=true&'
withRequest: { ... }
uponReceiving: 'GET /a1/configurations?includeDeleted=true&'
withRequest: { ... }
```

The value for `uponReceiving` needs to be unique if the `withRequest` details are different.

For best practice, I would recommend using a human-readable string (this helps with reporting):

```
uponReceiving: 'a request for configurations that are not deleted',
withRequest: { method: "GET", path: /a1/configurations, query: { includeDeleted: "false", } }
```

and later:

```
uponReceiving: 'a request for all configurations',
withRequest: { method: "GET", path: /a1/configurations, query: { includeDeleted: "true", } }
```